# Finding current (I) in a basic circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: Schematic]

This has been bothering me:

If I am told \$v_1 = -36\,\mathrm{V}\$ and \$v_2 = 18\,\mathrm{V}\$, how am I meant to find \$i\$?

I figured since \$v_1\$ is giving off a negative current it would be flowing in the opposite direction of \$i\$, and wouldn't the equation to find \$i\$ then become \$18-(-36)=i\$?

I thought about loop or nodal analysis but then I realized there aren't really any nodes, just loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're nodes. Just use ohm's law/nodal analysis. If you find \$ \frac{V_1}{8} =I_8 \$ you have one current flowing out of the node where V1 is. Then \$\frac{V_1-V_2}{6} = I_6 \$ is another current flowing away from node V1 (and into node V2). Then you do \$\frac{V_2}{4} = I_4 \$is a current flowing out of node V2. Now you have all the currents flowing into and out of both nodes except for i itself. But \$i\$ flows into one node and out the other node so you could write it like this:

At node V1:
$$ I_8+I_6+i = 0  $$
At node V2:
$$ I_6+ i = I_4 $$

Then sub in the voltage/resistance equations into the node equations.
Also note that you can simplify this if you realize that \$I_8 = -I_4 \$. That's one less variable to have to track down.

Use algebraic substitution or any other method you prefer to simplify your equations to solve for i.

Comment: Isn't \$i\$ just \$\frac{v_2 - v_1}{R_{EQ}}\$?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes. It's engineering. There's always more than one way to skin a cat. For a beginner, they may miss that the ground symbol doesn't absorb any current if there's no other ground symbol which would help simplify it down to what you say.

Comment: I made a really poor description. I realize there are 2 nodes, I am just lost as to what to use to find the current. Nodal analysis or KCL. The part that I am hung up on is whether or not the current coming out of the respective nodes is + or -

for example if I do a node analysis at v1, am I able to say that any current leaving is +, and any current coming in is -?

Comment: @KyleH What I tend to do is equate all the incoming currents on one side of the equals and all the outgoing currents on the other side of the equals. This should make sense as current can't disappear into a node, it has to go out the other nodes if it came in. You can choose which way you want the currents to go when you begin the analysis. Just make sure you stay consistent. If once you've solved the currents and you find that they're negative, understand that you chose the opposite direction. So the currents actually went the opposite way, but that doesn't mean you have to re-solve.

Comment: @KyleH It just means that your initial guess at which way the current went was wrong. But your value will be correct so long as you stayed consistent.

Comment: @horta, that's true, there is more than one way to skin a cat just as one can use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: @KyleH And just to try and clarify, at node V1 I guessed/chose to have all currents **leaving** the node. This meant that all the currents were added together. Since nothing went into the node, they all must sum to equal 0. Obviously, one or two of I8, I6, or *i* will come back as being negative because I chose *wrong*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri what's obvious to you due to years of experience or just being super bright may not be so obvious to someone just starting circuits. I'd rather give a student a sledgehammer as there're more uses for it than a nut-cracker, but that's just my preference :)

Comment: I am actually beginning to understand. In your original answer, how were you able to see that
i8 = -i4 ?
I guess why is it not i8 + i6 + i4 + i = 0?

Comment: @KyleH At the beginning I chose to make both i8 and i4 point downwards. Since the ground node isn't connected to anything else, what flows into the ground node must flow out. So if i8 goes in, then what must come out is the same i8. Except I just called that same current i4 except backwards. So that means i8 must be -i4 or i4 must be -i8. Had I chosen one to go down and one to go up, then they would be equal (and not opposite). I was only looking at the ground node to ID that i8 is equal and opposite i4. What node are you trying to use to get i8+i6+i4+i=0?

Comment: @horta, I suspect that the point of this particular circuit solution exercise is precisely that the ground symbol is irrelevant to the solution.  If it weren't there, the beginning student would simply combine the resistors into an equivalent resistance and use Ohm's law.  The fact that adding the ground symbol doesn't change the solution or solution method for this circuit is a valuable lesson to learn.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri right, but how would they come to that conclusion without using some more complicated analysis? If I thought current was leaving or entering through the ground node, I would never combine 8 and 4. My analysis only assumed that Gnd was at 0 volts.

Comment: From v1 you are able to say the current across the 6 ohm resistor is 18-(-36)/6 = i6. again on v1, you are able to say the current across the 8 ohm resistor is -36/8 = i8. 
switching to v2, you can just say the current across the 4 ohm resistor is 18/4 = i4. I cannot intuitively understand where to go from here despite knowing that each equation will be equal to 0 under KCL.

Comment: @KyleH Ok, assuming currents drawn the way you did it, it would be at V1: i6 in, i8 out, and i out so your equation for V1 is: i6-i8-i = 0 (or i6 = i8 + i)
at node V2: i6 out, i in, and i4 out so your equation there will be: i6 - i + i4 = 0 (or i6 + i4 = i)
You only need one of the equations to find i now because you know i6, i4, and i8. It should just be plug and chug. Using what you have and node V1 equation:
(18-(-36))/6 - (-36)/8 -i =0.  ->  
i= 56/6 + 9/2

Answer (score 2):

> I figured since v1 is giving off a negative current

That doesn't make any sense.  \$v_1\$ is a node voltage and can't be described as 'giving off current' one way or the other.

> I realized there aren't really any nodes, just loops.

There are three nodes.

Honestly, I think you're in over your head for even this simple circuit.  The solution is just a straight forward application of Ohm's law and combining series and parallel resistances.

Hint:  the voltage across the current source is \$v_2 - v_1 = 54V\$.  If you can find the equivalent resistance of the resistors, the current \$i\$ is found by Ohm's law.

---

Since another answer has been accepted, the solution is, by inspection:

$$i = \frac{v_2 - v_1}{R_{EQ}} = \frac{54}{6||(8+4)}A$$

Note:  you can exchange the position of the current source and 6 ohm resistor to more clearly see how to combine the resistors into the equivalent resistance.

---

I must comment that node voltage analysis isn't applicable here *since the node voltages are given*.

If you don't see the equivalent resistance method, then simply use Ohm's law and KCL:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9hDWf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using the voltages and resistances given, the resistor currents are easily calculated as shown.

Apply KCL at node 2 to find the current \$i\$:

$$i = 9 + 4.5 = 13.5A$$

which is identical to

$$i = \frac{54}{6||(8+4)} = \frac{54}{4} =  13.5A$$

Comment: Actually, this helped tremendously. I know you can combine the 8 ohm and 4 ohm resistors. that would then negate the ground node, and leave you with a 12 ohm resistor in parallel with a 6 ohm resistor. Giving you 12 || 6. For the voltage, you know since v2 is negative, that is has to be less than v1, so you are able to write v1 - v2 divided by 12 || 6. The hardest part for me is just finding out where to start which is why nodal analysis seems really abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The crude way:

1)Let's call the 6 ohm resistor R1, the 8 ohm resistor R2, and the 4 ohm resistor R3.

2)If v1 is -36V and v2 is 18V then the total voltage across them is 54V

3) With 54 volts across R1, the current through it must be I = E/R = 54V/6R = 8A

4)Since R2 and R3 are in series, their resistances add up to 12 ohms

5) With 54 volts across them, the current through them must be 4.5A

6)Since the 54 volt source is providing 8A into R1 and 4.5A into R2 and R3, all at the same time, the total current, i, will be 12.5 amperes.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your R1 current.

Comment: @copper.hat: I said it was crude, didn't I? ;)

Comment: You'll get a ticket from Kirchoff's police.

Comment: That happened once before, and when I refused to accept it they charged me with resisting arrest, shocking behavior, and then locked me in a Faraday cage for a while.

Comment: A lot of potential there...

Comment: True, but it's not currently available.

Comment: Looks like your Gauss is cooked then...